# How did Spike suffer so little damage?

Tags: cowboy-bebop, cowboy-bebop-2021

Near the end of the first season of the live-action Netflix version of *Cowboy Bebop*, Spike suffers a minor injury:

> Julia shoots him near the heart, he is launched through a glass window, and then falls what appears to be several hundred feet into water (and not with what one would call optimal diving positioning).

Bear in mind that this is at most a few days after he was caught in a serious explosion that left him unconscious, mere hours at most after being beaten by Vicious's minions, and a few *minutes* after being stabbed in the shoulder.

Yet when we next see him speaking with Jet, he is walking slowly and with a bit of a limp, but otherwise seems fine, and was presumably able to emerge from the water (i.e. not fainting and drowning) and travel some distance under his own power. It takes a good deal of alcohol before he even falls over (not even unconscious, at least initially). He does not appear to be dead, as would seem most likely, or unconscious and suffering from innumerable broken bones, as would seem all but inevitable.

Why is Spike in such (relatively) good shape after his fall? His combat skills already seem superhuman, so does he possess any modifications that would help him resist such serious injury?

Comment: This is a world with hyper-advanced medical care. We see a gunshot wound being cured within minutes in the opening episode using some sort of medical wand thingie

Comment: @Valorum - Medical care will not keep one conscious (or alive for that matter) after being shot through a window and falling hundreds of feet. Also, the medical care is good, but not *that* good: Spike is still tender and has bandages on his wounds after recovering from the explosion, Ana still has a limp from when she was stabbed in the leg, and so forth. In any case, Spike has no time for any treatment between receiving a brutal beating and being stabbed before he is shot out of a window hundreds of feet above the water.

Comment: The question is not whether he could be patched up if he survived those events and got back to some place with medical equipment. The question is how he managed to fall back-first out of a window with a gunshot wound to the chest, a stab wound to the shoulder, and assorted other injuries, land in the water hundreds of feet below without either dying from the impact or losing consciousness and drowning, and then, without any money or time for medical treatment, was able to walk back to the Bebop under his own power and meet Jet that same night. That is a frankly superhuman feat.